# Python- Pass control flow back to top of the script

Tags: python, function, control-flow

I am trying to fetch the contents of a page using Requests.The URL has 3 parameters:

1. Unique page ID
2. Username
3. Password

My initial block of code looks like this :

```
import requests

id = raw_input("Enter the unique id:")
user = raw_input("Enter your username:")
password = raw_input("Enter corresponding password:")

try:
    r = requests.get('http://test.com/request.pl?id=' + id, auth=(user, password))
    if r.status_code == 404:
        print "No such page exists.Please check the ID and try again"
        ## Ask for input again
    else:
        print r.text 
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print "Server is refusing connections.Please try after sometime"
    sys.exit(1)
```

My issue is on the commented line wherein i want the user to be prompted for the input again.How do I pass the control flow back to the top of the script.

I have a vague feeling that I might be doing this in a very crude way and there might be more elegant solutions using functions.If there are any,please do enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what actually you want.

```
import requests

def user_input():
    id1 = raw_input("Enter the unique id:")
    user = raw_input("Enter your username:")
    password = raw_input("Enter corresponding password:")

    try:
        r = requests.get('http://test.com/request.pl?id='+ id1 + user + password)
        if r.status_code == 404:
            print "No such page exists.Please check the ID and try again"
        ## Ask for input again
            user_input()
        else:
            print r.text
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print "Server is refusing connections.Please try after sometime"
        sys.exit(1)
user_input()
```

Comment: Using recursion might allow a user to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @Joshua..just to understand..what does the above statement mean ?

Comment: @Amistad Essentially, a malicious user could cause the entire program to crash by repeatedly inputting data that causes a 404 status code.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (but not necessarily the most extensible) way is to put everything in a `while True` loop.

```
import requests

while True:
    id = raw_input("Enter the unique id:")
    user = raw_input("Enter your username:")
    password = raw_input("Enter corresponding password:")

    try:
        r = requests.get('http://test.com/request.pl?id=' + id, auth=(user, password))
        if r.status_code == 404:
            print "No such page exists.Please check the ID and try again"
            ## control flow will reach the bottom and return to the top
        else:
            print r.text
            break
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print "Server is refusing connections.Please try after sometime"
        sys.exit(1) ## Exit condition of the loop
```

Comment: you should probably `break` on the else

Answer (score 2):

I would place this code in a while loop that always executes      while True:      and have a flag that allows you to break out of the loop appropriately.